# Deploying sidecar to prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have tried to deploy the `Prometheus Operator` With `Thanos` but I am not able to successfully deploy `Thanos` sidecar to `Prometheus pod` Can you help me where I am going wrong in deploying the `sidecar`.

I have deployed the `Prometheus operator` successfully in my cluster and then i have created the secret by following the below command

```sh
$ kubectl -n monitoring create secret generic thanos-objstore-config --from file=thanos.yaml=/tmp/thanos-config.yaml
```

Then I have verified the `Thanos` sidecar by the following command

```sh
$ kubectl describe po/prometheus-prom-op-prometheus-0 -n monitoring
```

where prom-op is the name of the Prometheus operator I have created.

But i cannot see the thanos sidecar deployed in the prometheus pod. Can anyone help me to solve the problem where i am doing wrong.

Comment: can you provide the yamls you used for deploying prometheus server?

Comment: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml    The above link is the yaml file i have used to depoloy the prometheus operator.  i have also changed the values.yaml file for thanos side car thanos:
    baseImage: improbable/thanos
    version: v0.2.1
    peers: thanos-peers.monitoring.svc:10900
    objectStorageConfig:
      key: thanos.yaml
      name: thanos-objstore-config

Comment: i have also created thanos.yaml in order to configure object store configuration and it contains: type: s3
config:
  bucket: test-prometheus-thanos
  endpoint: s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  encryptsse: true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it manual in the crd.

```
kubectl -n monitoring edit Prometheus prometheus-operator-prometheus
```

Then add

```
thanos:
  image: improbable/thanos:v0.6.0
  objectStorageConfig:
    key: object-store.yaml
    name: thanos
  version: v0.6.0
```